# What is the body of a text preceding a postscript called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

A postscript may be added to the end of a letter or email (she explained knowing that people on english.stackexchange.com would be unfamiliar with the term).  An afterword can be appended to the end of a book.  I'm using "P.S." farcically at the end of a Facebook comment.

Is there a generic term for the bodies of letters, emails, books, and Facebook comments?

Comment: I'd probably call it a "prescript", but then some people think I'd odd.

Comment: I had considered that, but I think a prescript would precede the body of the document, as the postscript follows it.

Comment: I tend to not be so prescriptive.

Comment: What’s wrong with ‘body’?

Comment: That may in fact be the word I'm looking for.  That, or document.  I was hoping for something a little more official and erudite.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&smoothing=3&content=body+of+the+text&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbody%20of%20the%20text%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbody%20of%20the%20text%3B%2Cc0